# How to restrict my app to landscape mode?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, orientation, landscape

I have my iPad application created using the SplitView template.
I wonder what is the best way to restrict my application to landscape mode?

I have tried overriding  `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` method in DetailViewController.m

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}
```

but ***4.2 GM is still buggy*** and it fails to show the controller view. What other choices do I have?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE1**

- I have already filed a bug report:
  [Bug ID #8620135](https://bugreport.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/RadarWeb.woa/8/wo/WXiBxARv7yUGJ0T3xJVYd0/5.83.28.0.9)
- My app is almost finished and I have to find a work-arround since I don't think they are going to solve this before 4.2 officially comes out (GM is already out!)

  In order to recreate the bug, just use SplitView template and override above method in any of the UIViewControllers (RootViewController or DetailViewControllers)

**UPDATE2**

I have found a work-around. (See UPDATE3 for the complete work-around)

Set UISupportedInterfaceOrientations only to support Landscape , this will force the app to start in landscape mode allowing DetailViewController to start correctly(hence shown correctly)

```
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
```

But if you rotate the device, it turns Portrait mode!!!, so *is still necessary to override* `shouldAutorotateToIntercafeOrientation`: as above

**Discussion:**

If this wouldn't be a bug I would expect a warning or execution error, exception or something when starting the app in a orientation that is not supported by the view controller. Besides, why only DetailViewController does not show? If this would be specification, then RootViewController should also fail to load then. Don't you think?
thanks for you help... ;)

**UPDATE3**

After further tests I have realized that above work-around does not work in some cases. For example when starting the app when the device is in landscape won't work!.
The real problem seems to be that in iOS4.2GM UISplitViewController needs all its controllers have all rotations to be available at its load time. So is necessary to trick him so it loads in Landscape mode and then not allow him to rotate its view controllers.

So here is the new work-around for this annoying iBug.

Step1:
Set Info.plist like so:

```
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
```

Step2
Set a new flag in DetailViewController.m or .h (from SplitView Template)

```
BOOL lockRotation = NO; //WORK-ARROUND: Bug ID# 8620135.

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    //WORK-ARROUND: Bug ID# 8620135.
    if (lockRotation) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
    }else{
        return YES;
    }
}
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //set NO here since this is called before shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation method is called
    lockRotation = NO; //WORK-ARROUND: Bug ID# 8620135.
}
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    //set YES as soon as possible, but after shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation method was called
    lockRotation = YES; //WORK-ARROUND: Bug ID# 8620135.
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE:**
 Please note that this bug only appears when the UISplitViewController is loaded and not everytime 
 the its view appears. Hence, to see this bug make sure the app was terminated before.

Comment: the question states you are making the change in DetailViewController, is that the correct controller to be overriding the method?

Comment: @Aaron it does not matter In what controller I make the change. (In RootViewController or DetailViewController) The result is the same.

Comment: basically UISupportedInterfaceOrientations, does absolutely nothing. To set the orientation when the app starts set UIInterfaceOrientation in the plist. (it's friendly name is Initial Interface Orientation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked a question with a bounty of 500 that [seems to be the same thing you're facing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3972001/height-and-width-on-iphone-ipad).

From my limited experience it is much easier to make a landscape-only iPhone app than a landscape-only iPad app. I'm not sure why there is any difference, but the steps Apple says to take to make it landscape-only do not work on their own.

Comment: I think I have found a hint in that thread, Here is what I did and it worked but this is surely a work-arround. This should not be necessary  I believe. See my update2.

Comment: Even tough I found myself the answer... this answer lead me to it. So thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this (it works):

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
    if(toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
        return YES;
    }
    else 
    {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: modify the 'if' condition according to what mode you want it in. The above code restricts it to landscape right. Change the 'if' check to UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft to lock left. For both landscape modes, do if(toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)

Comment: Didn't work... This is enough when not using UISplitViewController I believe.

Comment: `UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);` is Apple macro to do what you said in your answer shortly. So the asker has done what you said to do.

Comment: I mean, `UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);` is the same as your answer.

Comment: It's unfortunate that it did not work for the asker however like I said it worked for me and I have an app on the app store for iPad using a splitviewcontroller that is landscape only. I have used this way and it worked for me. Oh well...... as long as you found a solution all is good

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [iPhone app in landscape mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402/iphone-app-in-landscape-mode), if you haven't already. I was going to suggest simply adding UISupportedInterfaceOrientations to your Info.plist and specifying the two landscape orientations. But, apparently, this is not sufficient, according to answers to cited question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a BUG, I faced this problem also. It is something to do with

```
UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft
```

To replicate this situation:

1) Create a new iPad project using UISplitViewController template

2) Edit info.plist

```
Supported interface orientations
-Landscape (left home button)
-Landscape (right home button)
```

3) DetailViewController.m

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
//    return YES;
 NSLog(@"RotateToInterface:[%d] vs LandscapeLeft[%d]", interfaceOrientation, UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
 return interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
}
```

4) Run it....You will see a blank black view. and no matter how you turn. "UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft" never detected.

By the way, ***nacho4d***'s adding BOOL check work-around is working. Thumbs UP :)