# DetailView not loading in SplitViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios, uisplitviewcontroller

i managed using a SplitViewController in a TabBarApplication.
The problem now is, trying to start the Application (the SplitViewController is the first View in my TabbarApp) in Landscape mode the Detail View gets not loaded. Starting it in Portrait works fine, also after pushing my iPad to Landscape after starting in Portrait.

Here 2 Links:

[Starting in Portrait, switching to Landscape](http://cl.ly/e58e85f739fb60249b47)

[Starting in Landscape](http://cl.ly/022696f057e98a5cd624)

i've modified the `willShowViewController` method, because i couln't even start it in landscape

```
- (void)splitViewController: (UISplitViewController*)svc willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController invalidatingBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem {

    NSMutableArray *items = [[toolbar items] mutableCopy];
    //XLog("second: %i",[items count]);
    if([items count] > 0) {
        [items removeObjectAtIndex:0];
        [toolbar setItems:items animated:YES];
    }
    [items release];
    self.popoverController = nil;

}
```

the if query prevents my app from crashing in landscape.

i have no idea why my detailviewcontroller doesn't show up and my rootviewcontroller of the splitview shows up over the complete width.

any ideas?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specially in iOS 4.2 I believe that is a bug.
I have found a work-around and wrote it here:

[How to restrict my app to landscape mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4078429/ipad-uisplitviewcontroller-how-to-restrict-my-app-to-landscape-mode)

Hope it helps