# How to create an iPad app in only landscape right mode?

Tags: ipad, landscape

I am working on an iPad app and I want this app only in landscape mode. Please suggest me a suitable answer for this task.

Comment: I think this already has an answer

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4078429/how-to-restrict-my-app-to-landscape-mode

Answer (score 1):

set this in app target

[image]

this may help you